# Questions marked with blue background

Tags: support

In the list i noticed some questions has a blue background (eg [Trying to delete a column from a sharepoint document library view - SP2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11465/trying-to-delete-a-column-from-a-sharepoint-document-library-view-sp2010)). I first thought they were either answered or imported questions, but this doesnt seem to be the case. What causes the question to get this color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this question was tagged with your favorite tag.
(It's blue for me too, as my favorite tag is `Powershell`)

Comment: ah yeah thats it, I subscribed to that tag :-)